# How to set decision variables types like binary, int, double in Apache Commons Math SimplexSolver?

Tags: java, apache, solver, linear-programming, simplex

How to set decision variables types like binary, `int`, `double` in Apache Commons Math [`SimplexSolver`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/optimization/linear/SimplexSolver.html)? The output of the program below is this:

```
332.6666666666667
1.0
8331.666666666668
```

I want decision variables to be of type `int` not `double`; output should be `333, 0, 8325` if solved as integer decision variables.

```
public static void testSample() throws OptimizationException {
    LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[]{25, 15}, 0);
    Collection<LinearConstraint> constraints = new ArrayList<LinearConstraint>();
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{5, 8}, Relationship.LEQ, 5000));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{1, 4}, Relationship.LEQ, 1500));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{3, 2}, Relationship.LEQ, 1000));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{1, 0}, Relationship.GEQ, 1));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{0, 1}, Relationship.GEQ, 1));

    SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
    RealPointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(f, constraints, GoalType.MAXIMIZE, true);

    System.out.println(solution.getPoint()[0]);
    System.out.println(solution.getPoint()[1]);
    System.out.println(solution.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is convenient for this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format(solution.getPoint()[0]));
System.out.println(nf.format(solution.getPoint()[1]));
System.out.println(nf.format(solution.getValue()));
```

Console:

```
333
1
8,332
```

Addendum: This approach assumes that the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) is applied using real numbers and the result(s) rounded to integer. The package containing `SimplexSolver`, [`org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/optimization/linear/package-summary.html), offers no other implementation. As an alternative, consider a [different approach](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) or  `Maxtrix<Rational>`, available in [`JScience`](http://jscience.org/api/index.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. In your answer you are just formatting the number it has nothing to do with the optimization. 333 1 8332 is not the optimized answer the optimized solution is 333 0 8325. By setting the decision variable type we can get the real optimization. Is there any body know how to do that?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; more above. Sorry I edited your question in error.